# How to access resources in JAR file?

Tags: java, image, url, resources, jar

I have a Java project with a toolbar, and the toolbar has icons on it. These icons are stored in a folder called resources/, so for example the path might be "resources/icon1.png". This folder is located in my src directory, so when it is compiled the folder is copied into bin/

I'm using the following code to access the resources.

```
    protected AbstractButton makeToolbarButton(String imageName, String actionCommand, String toolTipText,
        String altText, boolean toggleButton) {

    String imgLocation = imageName;
    InputStream imageStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgLocation);

    AbstractButton button;
    if (toggleButton)
        button = new JToggleButton();
    else
        button = new JButton();

    button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
    button.setToolTipText(toolTipText);
    button.addActionListener(listenerClass);

    if (imageStream != null) { // image found
        try {
            byte abyte0[] = new byte[imageStream.available()];
            imageStream.read(abyte0);

            (button).setIcon(new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(abyte0)));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                imageStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else { // no image found
        (button).setText(altText);
        System.err.println("Resource not found: " + imgLocation);
    }

    return button;
}
```

(imageName will be "resources/icon1.png" etc). This works fine when run in Eclipse. However, when I export a runnable JAR from Eclipse, the icons are not found.

I opened the JAR file and the resources folder is there. I've tried everything, moving the folder, altering the JAR file etc, but I cannot get the icons to show up.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

(As a side question, is there any file monitor that can work with JAR files? When path problems arise I usually just open FileMon to see what's going on, but it just shows up as accessing the JAR file in this case)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To load an image from a JAR resource use the following code:

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
URL url = getClass().getResource("path/to/img.png");
Image img = tk.createImage(url);
tk.prepareImage(img, -1, -1, null);
```

Comment: What package is that Toolkit within?

Answer (score 11):

I see two problems with your code:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgLocation);
```

This assumes that the image file is in the same folder as the .class file of the class this code is from, not in a separate resources folder. Try this instead:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/"+imgLocation);
```

Another problem:

```
byte abyte0[] = new byte[imageStream.available()];
```

The method `InputStream.available()` does *not* return the total number of bytes in the stream! It returns the number of bytes available without blocking, which is often much less.

You have to write a loop to copy the bytes to a temporary `ByteArrayOutputStream` until the end of the stream is reached. Alternatively, use `getResource()` and the `createImage()` method that takes an URL parameter.

Answer (score 4):

The section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Icons](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) shows you how to create a URL and read the Icon in two statements.

Answer (score 0):

For example in a NetBeans project, create a resources folder in the src folder. Put your images (jpg, ...) in there.

Whether you use ImageIO or Toolkit (including getResource), you must include a leading / in your path to the image file:

```
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/resources/agfa_icon.jpg"));
setIconImage(image);
```

If this code is inside your JFrame class, the image is added to the frame as an icon in your title bar.