# Loading static resources from inside one-jar

Tags: java, jar, jetty

I have a web page hosted on jetty server. The page displays some static images, the images directory are kept inside a jar, say application.jar. This application.jar is packaged inside a one-jar. I am facing problem in accessing the images directory as they are inside a jar which is inside another jar.
I have tried almost all the ways to get URL of the images directory: class.getClassLoader().getResource(), Thread.currenctThread.getContextClassLoader().getResource(), ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(), etc. None of them is of any help. I wrote all these statements, i.e. tried to get access to the images directory, from a class that is inside the application.jar. This jar contains the images directory too.

If anybody has ever faced this before, please reply to this thread. I am open to any other ideas also that may help me achieve the objective.

Comment: Please show what you've tried, and the layout of the jar file.

Comment: Using getResource() you need get an input stream to the second jar, then use a JarInputStream to iterate over JarEntries. If you have control over the packaging, I would not recommend putting a JAR into a JAR.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/classpath/to/my/file");
```

You can find more here:

[How to read a file from jar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-can-i-read-file-from-jar-in-java)

[How to access resources in JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393194/how-to-access-resources-in-jar-file)