# How to load the image from a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, inputstream

This code works only if I  run my project, but if I run the Jar file, I get a NullPointerException. The image is in src directory.

```
try {
            URL resource = Sticker.class.getResource("\\transparentSticker.png");
            img = null;
            this.img = ImageIO.read(Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile());
            System.out.println("c");
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
        }
```

If I use this code, an IllegalArgumentException is being thrown.

```
InputStream input = Sticker.class.getResourceAsStream("\\transparentSticker.png");
        if (input == null) {
          
            input = Sticker.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("\\transparentSticker.png");
        }
            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

How to load the image?

Comment: 1) not sure why you are using the Paths class. The ImageIO.read(...) method will accept a URL as a parameter 2) did you include the file in your .jar file?

Comment: The argument to getResource and getResourceAsStream is not a filename, it’s a URL.  The backslash is not a legal character in a URL.  You probably meant `"/transparentSticker.png"`.  Also, as camickr said, don’t try to convert the URL to a file;  just load the URL directly.

Answer (score 0):

You did say the PNG is in the `src` folder?

Let's see, after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393194/how-to-access-resources-in-jar-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258244/accessing-a-file-inside-a-jar-file), I think it needs to be:

```
InputStream input = Sticker.class.getResourceAsStream("/src/transparentSticker.png");
```

or

```
URL resource = Sticker.class.getResource("/src/transparentSticker.png");
```

Think unix, not windows.